# Eloquent ID & Foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

My table `Cous` has a column `date_seance` with 2 recordings.

[image]

In my table `Retour`, I have to retrieve the `date_seance`.

[image]

Except that, I always retrieve the same value. 
Where is the `23/10/2019` one?

In my model `Cous` I have this:

```
public function retours()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Retour',
            'App\Eleve',
            'fk_cours', 
            'fk_eleve',
            'id', 
            'id' 
        );
    }
```

In my `Retour` `index.blade.php` I have this:

```
 @foreach($retours as $retour)
 <tr>
    <td> {{$retour->instruction}}</td>
    <td> {{$retour->description}}</td>
    <td> {{$retour->eleves->nom}}</td>  
    <td> {{$retour->eleves->prenom}}</td>  
    <td> {{$retour->eleves()->first()->cours()->first()->date_seance->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
    <td> {{$retour->eleves()->first()->cours()->first()->moniteurs->nom}}</td>
    <td> {{$retour->eleves()->first()->cours()->first()->moniteurs->prenom}}</td>
    <td> {{$retour->eleves()->first()->paiements()->first()->date_saisie->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
```

My problem is this line:

```
<td> {{ $retour->eleves()->first()->cours()->first()->date_seance->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
```

I don't understand my problem.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I updated your question and also modified the model you mentioned (from: "In my `Retour` model I have this" to: "In my `Cous` model I have this"). If this is incorrect just modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to mention.  First, calling your `eleves` relationship on your blade form like this:

```
$retour->eleves()
```

is going to go back to the database on every single call.  This could add up to a lot of delay if you have a lot of `retour` objects, or even if you just go through that table.

Strongly recommend eager loading as much as you can on at least the `retour` collection.

**On your controller**:

```
// Not sure if you had any constraints, but this will eager load eleves
$retours = Retour::with('eleves')->get();
```

The issue with your always pulling the same date is that you are *possibly* pulling from the same object.  I love a good chain... but sometimes longer chains become more confusing than they are worth.  Take a look at this line:

```
$retour->eleves()->first()->cours()->first()->date_seance
```

If you break this down from just the first loop on your blade page, you are pulling the first `eleves` from this first `retour` object from the overall collection of `retour` objects.  Then, you are pulling the first `cours` object from that first `eleves` from that first `retour` object.  The reason the date is the same is that you are *possibly* pulling the same `cours` object.  I say possibly because the `first()` method is just pulling the first instance associated with the `retour` object in the database.  Not the *latest*, just the first.  So, if there are multiple `eleves` for every `retour`, if the one with say `id` of 1 is attached to both the first and the second `retour`, you are pulling the same exact `eleves` in the second loop.  This is further compounded by exactly the same issue on the `cours` relationship with `eleves`.  If you have say a `cours` with `id` of 21 attached to multiple `eleves`, you *might* be pulling the exact same `cours` even though you are on a totally different loop for both `retour` and `eleves`.

To fix this, you need to have a solid handle on *which* `eleves` and *which* `cours` objects you are referring to in your loop.  I would recommend not querying at the top level (`retours`), but rather, having a couple of lower level queries on those relationships (`eleves` or `cours`) and loop directly on those in your blade.

E.g. **in your Controller**:

```
$courses = Cours::where('some constraint', $someConstrainer)->get()
```

Then, **in your blade**, just loop on the `$courses` collection:

```
@foreach($courses as $cours){
    // Other stuff here...
    <td> {{ $cours->first()->date_seance->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
```

If you can't do it at the `cours` level, perhaps back out one level higher and load with `eleves` (while eager loading the `cours` objects).

Comment: Thank you so much Watercayman for your explanations and the time you took to write to me.

I will change that and follow your steps.:-)